# Identifying what features in my iOS apps are used

Tags: iphone, ios, tracking, user-interaction

I have several iPhone/iPad apps on the App Store. I would like to add snippets of code in my apps that will identify user behavior. For example what features in the app are used the most or the least. Does anybody have a good idea on how to implement this kind of features in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event tracking in [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/).

For each user event you want to track, you would do something like this:

```
[tracker trackEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                 withAction:@"buttonPress"
                  withLabel:buttonName
                  withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
```

That way you can generate reports in analytics to see what is being used.  See their [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/events) docs for more details

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this works with un-published apps? Like, can I start seeing what the tracking info looks like in my Google Analytics account when using my app on my own device before publishing to the App Store?

Comment: It does, I'm using it at the moment to track what my testers are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate http://www.flurry.com into your app and set custom events for all of the parts of the app you want to know about. The report will give you a usage amount per session and you can directly identify what is being used.

Answer (score 1):

I use Flurry for all my apps and it works wonderfully. All kinds of helpful (for the right person) data. You can submit Events, like "User won level 608", and attach data in the form of a dictionary to them.

End result: I recommend Flurry.

www.flurry.com